# Microsoft Copilot Studio is ignoring the sources that I'm feeding it

Tags: microsoft-copilot

I gave it the Wikipedia article about Power BI. I then asked my Copilot a basic question like "What is Power BI?", and it said that it can't help me with that.

Either this thing is completely useless or I'm doing something wrong. For some reason, I didn't find any articles about this issue online.

Has anyone had this issue? How do you fix it?